# How to make a hold in triangle made from cube

Tags: blender

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9b2eF.png

See in this pic.

I want to make windows on the triangle.

But when I make a windows and put it on, it didn't look well..
(Triangle is made by Cube)

I want it to look like this..

https://i.stack.imgur.com/LHcMk.jpg
(Pic from my friend but he didn't tell me how to do it T_T)

I have use blender for just 2 days, maybe I'm noob.

Sorry for bad grammar, I'm not very well at English.